# check for same user name in database 3

Tags: c#, winforms

i just want to check whether that user  exist or not and if not then save in the database else show error message user already exist
before i used this command works perfectly

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from cntc_employee where emp_alias= @alias", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alias", this.alias.Text);
con.Open();

if(Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)
{            
    errorProvider1.SetError(alias,"Alias Already exist");
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

but in 3 tier i dont know how to use executescalar in my bll class in if ()section
in my bll class

```
private bool UserNameCheck(string alias) 
{
    if (??)
        throw new Exception("Alias Already exist");
    else
        return true;
}
```

in my dal class

```
public void UserNameCheck(string alias)
{
    string query6;
    try
    {
        OpenCnn();

        query6 = "Select count(*) from cntc_employee where emp_alias= '" + alias + "' ";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query6, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseCnn();
    }
}
```

Comment: in dll class i think i should return object does bool function returns object(i dont think so)
what is if cond exprn in bll class

Comment: I really don't get what you want... please explain what you want to achieve... what you just wrote didn't make much sense to me, sorry.

Comment: i want to check if user exist or not in database using 3 tier 
can u rewrite my BLl class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with the Data Access Layer. While your logic seems correct, I argue the way you return objects. In my opinion, you'd better return a boolean indicating whether the user exists or not. Also, use parameterised queries, because you don't want SQLInjection. See code:

```
// Note: I changed the name to a more meaningfull use
public static bool UserExists(string alias)
{
    bool userExists = false;
    try
    {
        // Note: where do you initialise cmd?
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("alias", alias);
        cmd.CommandText = "Select count(*) from cntc_employee where emp_alias=@alias";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        OpenCnn();
        int amountOfUsersWithAlias = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if(amountOfUsersWithAlias > 0)
              userExists = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseCnn();
    }
    return userExists;
}
```

So now you have a booleanvalue indicating if the user exists. If the returnvalue is true, the users exists. If it is false, the user doesn't exist.

Now, in your Businesslayer, you call the above method:

```
public bool UserNameCheck(string alias)
{
    if (UserClass.UserExists(alias))        
        return true
    else            
        return false;
}
```

You call the static method for the correct alias. Again, true or false gets returned, depending on whether the user exists. You then use this method in your presentationlayer and show the error to the user if true is returned.

It may not be perfect 3-tier architecture, but it does the job.

Comment: whats userclass in Bll

Comment: I assume your method is in a class... I have made a static method so you can call it using class.UserExists. You could also make it non-static and use a Class myClass = new Class(); Then myClass.UserExists(alias).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String UserNameCheck(String alias) 
{
String returnValue = String.Empty;
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = null;
DataTable dt = null;
try
{
OpenCnn();
cmd =new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "Select count(*) from cntc_employee where emp_alias=@alias"; 
cmd,Parameter.Clear();
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@alias", alias);
dt = new DataTable();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(dt);
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
returnValue = "userNameIsExist";
else
returnValue = "userIsNotFound";
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
throw ex; 
} 
finally 
{ 
if(dt != null) { dt.Dispose(); dt = null; }
if(adapter != null) { adapter.Dispose(); adapter null; }
if(cmd != null) { cmd.Parameter.Clear(); cmd.Dispose(); cmd = null; }
CloseCnn();
}
return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the kind of thing you should use a `stored procedure` for.
Consider the following scenario:

2 users submit the same user name on the same time. your code goes to the database, checks if the user name exists, returns false for both, and then inserts the same user name for both users.

Instead of checking if the user name exists in one query and insert it in another, you can use a stored procedure to do both of these actions thus ensuring that you will not attempt to add the same user name twice.
I would also recommend to create a `unique constraint` on the user name (maybe an index, maybe even the primary key, depending on your needs) on the user name for that database table.

Try the following sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_InsertUser (
    @RequestedUserName nvarchar(10),
    @OutUserAlrearyExists bit OUTPUT
)
AS

SET @OutUserAlrearyExists = 1
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TblUsers
    WHERE Users_UserName = @RequestedUserName
) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TblUsers(Users_UserName) VALUES (@RequestedUserName)
    SET @OutUserAlrearyExists = 0
END

GO
```

Then in your code all you have to do is execute this stored procedure.
This also gives to another advantage - instead of going to the databse 2 time you go only once.

Answer (score -1):

try this (private):

```
        private int UserExistCheck(string alias)
    {
        string query6;
        try
        {
            OpenCnn();

            query6 = "Select count(*) from cntc_employee where emp_alias= '" + alias + "' ";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query6, con);
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //-- or ExecuteNonQuery()
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            CloseCnn();
        }
    }
```

and this (public) :

```
        public bool UserNameCheck(string alias)
    {
        if (UserExistCheck(alias) > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Alias Already exist");

        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

hope help you

EDIT:

PersonDAL :

```
    public class PersonDAL
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TutTestConn"].ToString();

    public PersonDAL()
    {

    }

    public int Insert(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("InsertData", conn);
        dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
            return dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//-- if combination of user name and
        }                                 // password are not unique throw exception
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dCmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }}
```

and PersonBAL:

```
public class PersonBAL
{
    public PersonBAL()
    {

    }

    public int Insert(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        PersonDAL pDAL = new PersonDAL();
        try
        {
            return pDAL.Insert(firstName, lastName, age);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            pDAL = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry sir m using 3 tier and there must be objected created in bll class

Comment: Demonstration of SQL injection without any comments can't really be considered an answer. Consider adding some comments explaining your code and fixing SQL injection part.